# How do I count the number of times a specific name appears in a pandas data frame column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of names. I need to get a count of how many times a specific name appears in that column.

```
Column:
Dave
John
John
Thanos
Bob
```

I need something like:

```
[in] df['Column'].count_name('John')
[out] 2
```

Using `value_counts()` doesn't work because there are thousands of names in the column, and many of them only appear once. I'm sorry if this question has been asked/answered before, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to search for it that doesn't just give me an answer telling me to use `value_counts()`.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `df['Column'].eq('John').sum()`

Comment: IF I HAD A SOUL I WOULD PLEDGE IT TO YOU, THANK YOU

Comment: `value_counts()` will be less performant than the sum for a single lookup. But if this needs to be done many times for different `Names`, you should store the result and use `.loc` to index: `s = df['Column'].value_counts()` followed by `s.loc['John']`

Answer (score 1):

Just for speed up using `numpy.count_nonzero`

```
import numpy as np 

np.count_nonzero(df['Column']=='John')
Out[186]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

`df['Column:'].value_counts()['John']`

```
In [6]: %timeit df[0].value_counts()['John']
1000 loops, best of 3: 548 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit df[0].eq('John').sum()
The slowest run took 8.19 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 311 µs per loop

In [8]: %timeit np.count_nonzero(df[0]=='John')
10000 loops, best of 3: 162 µs per loop
```

EDIT: Fastest is using np.count_nonzero...

Apparently, using eq() proves to be faster than using value_counts() which is obvious as value_counts calculates counts for all values whereas .eq() calculates for only given value..

Comment: But still can expert care to explain the difference in timings in second and third approaches please? I think they are apparently similar..